# Как получить структуру атомов из файла PDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, biopython

Нужно получить информацию о том, как именно связаны атомы в белке в файле PDB.
Идеальный вариант, как я вижу - это список кортежей, в каждом из которых будет по паре атомов, которые непосредственно соединены.

Я пытался искать разные варианты решения данной проблемы, нашёл класс `NeighborSearch` в `biopython`. Но объяснения того, что он из себя подразумевает я не смог найти НИГДЕ! Проведя дальнейшее исследование я пришёл к выводу, что он просто показывает атомы, которые находятся друг от друга на каком-то заданном расстоянии, БЕЗ УЧЁТА ТОГО, СВЯЗАННЫ ОНИ СВЯЗЬЮ ИЛИ НЕТ!

К слову сказать, я был удивлён, что не сумел пока обнаружить нужный мне инструмент, ведь существует не мало программ для чтения PDB-файлов, которые строят их структуру для 3D-показа. Как-то же они это делают. И странно что никто ещё не сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Хотя, уверен, я просто плохо искал. Надеюсь, кто-то сталкивался с этим, либо знает что использовать чтобы получить информацию о связи атомов. Спасибо!

Comment: Оно http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_Data_Bank_(file_format) , http://pymmlib.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: Дружище, значит тебе крупно повезло!
Действуй!
только зайди по ссылке выше )